Create Quarto PDF output by only compiling changed QMD-Files
I like to compile only QMD-files that have changed during the last build to generate PDF faster.
I was successfull in doing that for HTML Output using Makefile:
OUTPUT_DIR = output
HTML_DIR   = ${OUTPUT_DIR}/html

FILES_CONTENT  = index.qmd a.qmd b.qmd c.qmd \
                 figure.svg
FILES_GEN_HTML = _quarto.yml logo.svg styles.css theme.scss
FILES_OUT_HTML = ${HTML_DIR}/index.html ${HTML_DIR}/a.html ${HTML_DIR}/b.html ${HTML_DIR}/c.html


html:   ${HTML_DIR}/index.html ${FILES_OUT_HTML}

${HTML_DIR}/index.html: $(FILES_GEN_HTML)
    mkdir -p ${HTML_DIR}
    quarto render --output-dir ${HTML_DIR}

${HTML_DIR}/%.html: %.qmd
    quarto render $< --output-dir ${HTML_DIR}

This results in bulding a single HTML file, if only one QMD file was modifed since last build.
After building the PDF file (Quarto-Latex)
quarto render --profile book --output-dir output/pdf

I tried to rebuild only "a.qmd":
quarto render a.qmd --profile book --output-dir output/pdf

But this results in building the whole project. Actually parameter "a.qmd" was ignored.
Investigating the output ...
ls output/pdf
MyProject.pdf   a.html       b.html       c.html
logo.svg        styles.css   index.html   site_libs

... it seems that quarto "compiles" QMD files to HTML files as preperation for generating the PDF.
So I need quarto to tell: Compile "a.qmd" to "output/pdf/a.html" and then build the fresh generated and existing HTML files to a PDF file.
